# Is it possible to break alerts in one site collection with client-side scripting?

Tags: javascript, site-collection, alert

We have a single site collection where alerts have been down for some time. After review, it was suggested that client-side Javascript (common ones like EasyTabs and SPServices) could break alerts. I'm skeptical of that but wanted to see if it's even possible for client side changes to break alerts.

Comment: They sure could, if they are badly written or referenced in a way that overwrites standard SharePoint variables in the `window` namespace. Never had a problem with SPServices, so you could probably out rule that file. I would start by removing all custom scrip references to see if that works, then add them back one by one till it breaks

Comment: Do you mean like List alerts when content changes, or the actual javascript alerts?

Comment: @PirateEric, great question! I took for granted we where talking modal dialogs

Comment: I'm just talking OOTB list alerts.

Comment: Do you have any users listed under site settings -> user alerts? There is an exceptionally remote chance some javascript could interfere with alert  subscription, but virtually none that it could break existing subscriptions -- all emailing routines are run server side

Comment: Yes - there are at least 100 sites in the collection - most have many users with alerts set up. Subscribing actually works fine and you get the 'you've added an alert' notice - but nobody is receiving anything.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on scripts, but you can fallback to default master on one of the sites to eliminate doubt